# Any way to inverse a permutated Kronecker product when one participant matrix is known?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know there is a way to inverse a Kronecker product. See this question [reverse Kronecker product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60399/method-to-reverse-a-kronecker-product).

If I have a permutated Kronecker product of $A$ and $B$, that is $P(A\otimes B)Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are unknown permutation matrices of rows and columns, and $B$ is known, is there any way to obtain $A$?

Thought it would be easy, but it really exhaust me.

Comment: No.  In particular, $(e_1e_1^T) \otimes I$ can be permuted to $$(e_ne_n^T) \otimes I$$ with the right choice of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Not quite sure I've got your idea. What's $e_{1}$ and $e_{n}$?

Comment: Standard basis vectors