# Proving a matrix has Kronecker product form

Tags: permutations, tensor-products, kronecker-product

Is there a property unique to Kronecker product of two matrices, so that one could use it to prove that a certain matrix has Kronecker product form? Is there a proof technique to this type of objective?

An *example* problem is the following:
Prove that if $P = \{P_i\}$ is the group of **all** permutation matrices that commute with a particular matrix $A$: $A P_i = P_i A$, and similarly $Q = \{Q_j\}$ has **all** permutations commuting with $B$, $Q_j B = B Q_j$, then ALL permutations that commute with $A \otimes B$ have Kronecker product form: 
$$W (A \otimes B) = (A \otimes B) W \quad \Rightarrow  \quad W = P_i \otimes Q_j$$

In this example, our goal is to show that $W$ has a Kronecker form. Is there any technique to use for this type of proof?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the case of a square matrix $n \times n$ matrix $W$.

You have to consider all ways of writing $n$ as the product of two numbers $n=pq$.

Let us take for simplifying the formulas to come that $n=6$ with $p=2$ and $q=3$.

For each such writings consider a partition of $W$ in $q$ times $p \times p$ blocks under the form :

$$W=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
    W_{11}& W_{12}& W_{13}\\
\hline
W_{21}& W_{22}& W_{23}\\
\hline
W_{31}& W_{32}& W_{33}
\end{array}\right]
$$

Identify one of the blocks having at least one nonzero entry. Assume for the sake of simplicity that it is the upper-left block $W_{11}$; call it $B$.

Then, **under the condition that all other blocks are proportional to $B$**, i.e., giving $W$ the following aspect :

$$W=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
    B&aB&bB\\
\hline
cB&dB&eB\\
\hline
fB&gB&hB
\end{array}\right]
=A \otimes B \ \ \text{with} \ \ A:=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
    1&a&b\\
    c&d&e\\
    f&g&h
\end{array}\right]
$$

Please note the lack of unicity : $A \otimes B = kA \otimes \tfrac{1}{k}B $ for any non zero real number $k$.

Remark : the cases where $W$ is a rectangular matrix $n_1 \times n_2$ can be treated in a very similar manner, this time by considering the different ways to write $n_1=p_1q_1$ and $n_2=p_2q_2$.

Comment: well, this is simply the definition or Kronecker product. I was hoping for a simpler function that assures you a matrix has Kronecker product form. For example, your suggestion does not seem make the problem I pose as an example any easier, does it?

Comment: In my humble opinion, it is a little more operational than a simple copy of the definition. Anyway, I would be surprized that there is a simple criteria, first of all because you don't know a priori the dimensions of the components $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The problem is not with dimensions, you can assume that I know them. Again, please consider the example problem I give. You can assume we know the dimension of these matrices. How can we prove the claim? what sort of technique would you use there?

Comment: An interesting answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/321424 even if it is not directly interesting for your issue...

Comment: In fact, I think that this "nearest Kronecker product" brings a valuable answer. Googling with these keywords brings interesting pointers such as one can  find here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91651

Comment: This is about optimizing to fit a matrix in Kronecker product form. My question is different: again please see the example application. As the example suggests, I'm not looking to solve anything numerically.